# Reload tableview with data from a Modal swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I try to access my data from my Modal to my ViewController and
in my VC I try to Reload my Tableview but it does not work, but I get no errors.
I have checked so that I get the data from my database (firebase) by print it my console.

Here is my code.
//MY ViewControlller

```
 // Load the user's contacts into the TableView (My ViewController)
    func loadContacts(willFilter: Bool){
        //contacts = MyContacts().contacts
        if willFilter {
            contactController.filterContacts()
        }
        contactTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

//My modal

```
import Firebase
struct MyContacts {​​​​​​​​

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let currentUser = CurrentUser()
let fav = ContactsViewController?.self
var filteredContacts : [Contact] = []

    var contacts : [Contact] {​​​​​​​​

        var myContacts = [Contact]()

let collection = db.collection("users").document(currentUser.email).collection("contacts")

        collection.getDocuments() {​​​​​​​​ (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err {​​​​​​​​

print("Error getting documents: \(err)")

            }​​​​​​​​ else {​​​​​​​​

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {​​​​​​​​

                    if let contactID = document.data()["id"] as? String, let contactUsername = document.data()["name"] as? String{​​​​​​​​

                        let contactEmail = document.documentID

                        let contact = Contact(username: contactUsername, email: contactEmail, id: contactID)

                        myContacts.append(contact)
                    }​​​​​​​​
                }​​​​​​​​

                DispatchQueue.main.async {​​​​​​​​

                }​​​​​​​​
            }​​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​​

        return myContacts
    }​​​​​​​​

}​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: You cannot `return myContacts`. Well, you can, but it will still be empty when you do. Please learn about what _asynchronous_ means. And guess what, I'm here to help you do that! http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have read the link. But do you have any solution or suggestion for my problem? @matt

Answer (score 0):

can you try reloading it in the main thread:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {​​​​​​​​
   
    contactTableView.reloadData()
 }​​​​​​​​
```

and it's better to get your contacts in a completion instead of returning it.